# Bootstrap Navbar Spacing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

First here is my Plunker code: http://plnkr.co/edit/lh9t3ThQrJF3Tauv5Sno?p=preview

Please note that you should expand the preview pane to the left in order to see all of the elements.

What I'm trying to do is reduce the spacing between the red `(X)` (remove symbol) and the `item`. Basically when you press the red `(X)` the `item` is removed from the `navbar`. Right now it doesn't look right at all with the huge spacing between the two. I've tried using other elements such as `span`, `<a>`, `padding`, `margin`, and they all doesn't seem to be too compatible with the `navbar` as it seems to only like `<li>` in terms of alignment and spacing.

What else can I do to get the spacing to come closer between the red `(X)` and `item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8ZawD/2 (navbar collapse classes disabled for convenience)

```
.icon-remove-sign {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Tested in Chrome, FF, and IE10 on Win7/64.

Here's an updated answer based on the comments below. Note that I modified the HTML to make it more logical from an accessibility standpoint.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8ZawD/4/

Comment: Thank you for your help but that did't do it. It moved the red (X) further away from the item. I need them close to the item.

Comment: It's hard to tell what "the item" is in your code. I had assumed that the close button was for the list item to its left. It shouldn't be its own list item.

Comment: I apologize for the miscommunication. When I said item I was referring to item1, item2. But you did got me in the right direction as I didn't know we could use negative values for margin. Instead I moved the item1, item2 by giving them negative margins and it looks as I wanted.

Comment: Answer updated in case it helps someone else. Thanks for the accept.